# How can I reformulate an LP whose variables are linked to other LPs?

Tags: linear-programming, constraint, lp

I consider an LP ($LP^*$) having an objective function defined as follows:

$$\max_{x, y} \sum_{i \in I} p_i(x_i) - \sum_{j \in J} q_j(y_j)$$

where $x_i = \sum_{k \in [m]} x_{ik}$ and $y_j = \sum_{l \in [n]}y_{jl}$.

$p_i$ is a function of $x_i$ and is the objective function value of another LP ($LP^1_i$):

$$p_i(x_i) = \max_{x_{ik}} \sum_{k \in [m]} x_{ik} a_{ik}\\
s.t. ...$$

$q_j$ is a function of $y_j$ and is the objective function value of another LP ($LP^2_j$):

$$q_j(y_j) = \min_{y_{jl}} \sum_{l\in[n]}y_{jl} b_{jl}\\
s.t. ...$$

I want to bring $LP^*$ into a form such that I can use standard LP solvers (e.g. Gurobi in Java). What I tried so far is to integrate the constraints of $LP^1_i$ and $LP^2_j$ for all $i\in I$ and $j \in J$ into $LP^*$ and replace $p_i(x_i)$ and $q_j(y_j)$ with their definitions (as in $LP^1_i$ and $LP^2_j$) in the objective function. However, this approach seems not to be correct, since I am omitting the $\max$ and $\min$ of $LP^1$ and $LP^2$. That is, the resulting $x_i$ and $y_j$ of $LP^*$ will not be optimal for $LP^1_i$ and $LP^2_j$, but only feasible solutions.

Could someone help?

Comment: This can be related to “bilevel optimization”.

Comment: Does LP* have any constraints?

Comment: @Riley Yes, it does.

Comment: @user12632521 any that link `x` and `y`?